# Move the selected objects from and to position inside the array by given index, angular

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, angular

i have array of objects and the two select box with some values in from and to select box(index), where i am trying to move the object "from"(index) selected position "to"(index) selected position and vice versa in the given array     without changing the index or position values of other objects. 
The logic which i am using is working if i select the value from select box less then "to" select box its somewhat working but otherwise it wont.

Below is the code and logic which i am trying hard to move the value  but its not working.

```js
import {
  Component,
  OnInit
} from "@angular/core";

@Component({
  selector: "my-app",
  templateUrl: "./app.component.html",
  styleUrls: ["./app.component.css"]
})
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
  name = "Angular";
  data = [{
      id: "fmgbwe45",
      age: 24,
      gender: "male"
    },
    {
      id: "kjregh23",
      age: 27,
      gender: "female"
    },
    {
      id: "kjfdhg87",
      age: 30,
      gender: "male"
    },
    {
      id: "lsdjfk43",
      age: 10,
      gender: "female"
    },
    {
      id: "lsdjfk43",
      age: 15,
      gender: "female"
    },
    {
      id: "lsdjfk43",
      age: 14,
      gender: "female"
    },
    {
      id: "lsdjfk43",
      age: 50,
      gender: "female"
    },
    {
      id: "lsdjfk43",
      age: 19,
      gender: "female"
    }
  ];
  from: "";
  to: "";

  ngOnInit() {}

  changeSelect(event, value) {
    if (value === "from") this.from = event.target.value;
    else this.to = event.target.value;
    // console.log(this.to, "====", this.from);
    this.data.forEach((item, i) => {
      if (this.to && this.from) {
        let f = this.data.splice(parseInt(this.from), 1)[0];
        var d = this.data.splice(parseInt(this.to), 0, f);
        console.log(this.data, f);
      } else {}
    });
  }
}
```

```html
<h2>pretty-print:</h2>
<form action="/action_page.php">

  <label for="cars">Choose a from index:</label>
  <select name="cars" (change)="changeSelect($event,'from')">
    <option *ngFor="let data1 of data; let i = index" [value]="i+1">{{data1.age}}+ {{i+1}}</option>

  </select>
  ==
  <label for="cars">Choose a To index:</label>

  <select name="cars" (change)="changeSelect($event,'to')">
    <option *ngFor="let data1 of data; let i = index" [value]="i+1">{{data1.age}}+ {{i+1}}</option>

  </select>
  <div *ngFor="let data1 of data; let i = index">
    <pre>{{data1 | json}} + {{i+1}} </pre>
  </div>
</form>
```

Please help me to resolve or correct me if i am going wrong in selecting index values.

below is the example in which i want the data to be displayed:

i am selecting index val "from" = 6, "to" = 3
below is the object i require

```js
{
  "id": "fmgbwe45",
  "age": 24,
  "gender": "male"
} + 1 
{
  "id": "kjregh23",
  "age": 27,
  "gender": "female"
} + 2 
{
  "id": "lsdjfk43",
  "age": 14,
  "gender": "female"
} + 3 // this is moved from 6rd position to 3th position or index, other in same position
{
  "id": "lsdjfk43",
  "age": 10,
  "gender": "female"
} + 4 
{
  "id": "lsdjfk43",
  "age": 15,
  "gender": "female"
} + 5 
{ 
  "id": "kjfdhg87",
  "age": 30,
  "gender": "male"
} + 6 // this is moved from 3rd position to 6th position or index
{
  "id": "lsdjfk43",
  "age": 50,
  "gender": "female"
} + 7 
{
  "id": "lsdjfk43",
  "age": 19,
  "gender": "female"
} + 8
```

Below is the link for the code:

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-prettyprint-xhhzsk?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this way

```
import { Component, OnInit } from "@angular/core";

@Component({
  selector: "my-app",
  templateUrl: "./app.component.html",
  styleUrls: ["./app.component.css"]
})
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
  name = "Angular";
  data = [
    { id: "fmgbwe45", age: 24, gender: "male" },
    { id: "kjregh23", age: 27, gender: "female" },
    { id: "kjfdhg87", age: 30, gender: "male" },
    { id: "lsdjfk43", age: 10, gender: "female" },
    { id: "lsdjfk43", age: 15, gender: "female" },
    { id: "lsdjfk43", age: 14, gender: "female" },
    { id: "lsdjfk43", age: 50, gender: "female" },
    { id: "lsdjfk43", age: 19, gender: "female" }
  ];
  from: "";
  to: "";

  ngOnInit() {}

  changeSelect(event, value) {
    if (value === "from") this.from = event.target.value;
    else this.to = event.target.value;
    if (this.from && this.to) {
      let tempSequence = this.data[parseInt(this.from) - 1];
      this.data[parseInt(this.from) - 1] = this.data[parseInt(this.to) - 1];
      this.data[parseInt(this.to) - 1] = tempSequence;
      console.log(this.data);
    }
  }
}
```

**component.html**

```
<h2>pretty-print:</h2>
<form action="/action_page.php">

  <label for="cars">Choose a from index:</label>
<select name="cars" (change)="changeSelect($event,'from')" >
  <option *ngFor="let data1 of data; let i = index" [value]="i+1">{{data1.age}}+ {{i+1}}</option>

</select>
==
  <label for="cars">Choose a To index:</label>

<select name="cars" (change)="changeSelect($event,'to')" >
  <option *ngFor="let data1 of data; let i = index" [value]="i+1">{{data1.age}}+ {{i+1}}</option>

</select>
<div *ngFor="let data1 of data; let i = index">
<pre >{{data1 | json}} + {{i+1}} </pre>
</div>
</form>
```

Comment: hi, why did you take two array i am little confused there.

Comment: just because the dropdown you have use is the same array you are manipulating , thats why i have taken another array to manipluate and static array for the dropdown

Comment: sry i forget to edit the component.html file please check now @vinuta

Comment: @NarendraChouhan newData array is just to show you output, that is not required. you can remove it.

Comment: @AakashGarg here newData array is the value for the dropdown which user need to show, https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-prettyprint-xhhzsk?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts check this

Comment: @AakashGarg now how do you expect to run this successfully

Comment: @NarendraChouhan check the updated code for html, i changed newData to data.

Comment: yaa but it will manipulate the dropdown value also @AakashGarg

Comment: @NarendraChouhan OP asked to maintain previous sequence in dropdown?

Comment: NO, but then my function wont work can you edit that too

Comment: @NarendraChouhan i dnt want a new array i want to use the old array.